# Slices vs queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

It all started with me trying to apply slices to a queryset to limit it. As I understand the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) it is supposed to limit the results to 10 entries:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

    qs = Message.objects.all()  
    qs = qs.filter(Target_id=self.dialog)[:10]    # here the limit
    qs = qs.annotate(sender_id=Max('Sender__id')) 
    return qs
```

But really in template the request returns me all the records, but applies the annotation only to the first 10. I do not know why.

I thought the whole reason was annotate.

Then I remove the last line (with annotate). However I got in the template all the records instead of 10. That is same result as if I didn't make the slice.

In my template I'm not doing anything unusual: the iteration over the my queryset:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  {{message}}
{% endfor %}
```

This is weird: if I take `len(qs)` in my view, I get 10! But in template I get 300! It doesn't fit in my head.

I tried also to apply slice in the template instead of my view:

```
{% for message in messages|slice:":10" %}
```

But nothing has changed.

I have got all messages in my template instead of 10. How could this be?

PS: database type is sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [documented that it is not advisable to futher modify a queryset after slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> Also note that even though slicing an unevaluated `QuerySet` returns another unevaluated `QuerySet`, **modifying it further** (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) **is not allowed**, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.

You should change the order, like:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return Message.objects.filter(Target_id=self.dialog).annotate(
        sender_id=Max('Sender__id')
    )[:10]
```

So you *first* `.filter(..)`/`.annotate(..)`, and then you slice.